# Como seria acceso a esa estructura de datos desde jquery

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Deseo mostrar esta estructura de datos desde Jquery pero no logro, dejo parte del código, al realizar la consulta con postman veo todo el contenido pero cuando intento mostrar utilizando jquery solo muestra cabeceras.

```
  {
             "DOC": [
                {
                  "Doc": 2,
                  "Est": "P2"
                },
                {
                   "Doc": 4,
                   "Est": "P3"
                 }
                    ],
            "ID": [
                    {
                  "Car": 1,
                  "Est": "P3"
                    }
                 ],
            "TOTAL": 7
        }

success: function(result){ 
var documento= result.DOC;

    for ( var i in documento) {
        var d= documento[i].Doc;
        var e= documento[i].est;
        console.log(d);
        console.log(e);
    }
```

Comment: Primero debes *parsear* el resultado antes de poder usarlo: `success: function(response) { var result = JSON.parse(response); ... }`. Verifica eso y comenta los resultados. Saludos

Comment: {DOC: Array(0), CARNET: Array(0), SUMA: 0}EST: []Doc: []SUMA: 0__proto__: Object
3  undefined / Es lo que obtengo